# Count the number of digits in a hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, hex

I am trying to count the number of digits that are available in a hexadecimal number. For example: `0x00000001` should return the count as `8`.

Could anyone suggest as to what is the most efficient way of doing this? I have tried converting it to a `CString` and get the length using '`GetLength()`' but that doesn't seem to work here.

**Edit:** Sorry if I forgot to mentioned, my variable that stores the hexadecimal number is an unsigned short.

Tried this:

```
unsigned short number;
CString HexValue;
HexValue.Format("%.8x",number);     // number = 0000000000000000, 16 0's
HexValue = "0x" + HexValue;
int length = HexValue.GetLength() - 2; // returns an 8 here
```

Comment: All hex numbers will have 8 digits. What is the issue?

Comment: Well, I am trying to use this to catch an error in my program that somehow returns more than 8 digits.

Comment: Converting to a string and then getting the string length is the simplest solution, and what I would have suggested. What's not working with it for you?

Comment: @Emulator: `x > 255` will catch the case where more than 8 digits are needed.

Comment: @Kangkan: What about 8, 16 or 64 bit hex numbers?

Comment: Or 36? There's a reason we have CHAR_BIT and sizeof.

Comment: `HexValue.Format("%.8x",number);     // number = 0000000000000000, 16 0's` I dont get this. Number is a 16 BIT number. Thats 16 characters in BINARY encoding, not HEX encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since each byte contains two hexadecimal digits, try for a variable `n`of integral type

```
sizeof(n)*CHAR_BIT/4
```

Comment: Because bytes don't necessarily have 8 bits. `sizeof(n)*CHAR_BIT/4` is the portable answer.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Thanks for reminding of non-Intel architectures, corrected.

Answer (score 3):

If *0x00000001* is a string then `GetLength() - 2` should give 8. If it is a value stored in a different type (lets say int), then just simply remember the fact that hex encoding needs 2 characters per 8 bits to encode the whole value range (`sizeof(int) * 2`)

Comment: @ Morten: I am having an error for something like 0x0000000000000000 i.e. 16 0's and I need to catch this error. I tried your technique, but the length part returns a -2.

Comment: @Emulator: the length part will likely return an incorrect value if your string doesn't have the "0x" at the front - which it generally won't unless you explicitly add it when creating the string from the int.

Comment: `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT/4` to cover both bytes-per-int and bits-per-byte.

Comment: @Emulator : 16 zeroes in HEX is NOT the same as an unsigned short (16 bits), it is however a 64 bit number. 16 bits will encode to 4 characters in HEX.

Answer (score 1):

There is one hex digit per 4 bits.

```
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned short) * CHAR_BIT / 4 << "\n";
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned short) * CHAR_BIS % 4 << " LEFTOVER PARTIAL DIGITS\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of digits in a hexadecimal number *n* is max(1, ceil(log2(*n*))). See [Wikipedia, Binary logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Integer) for a fast algorithm to compute log2.

That won't give you the value 8 for `0x00000001`, though, since there's actually only digit needed to represent that number. The difference between `0x00000001` and `0x1` is a display issue only.

Comment: Will it return `8` for `0x00000001`?

Comment: @Nawaz: no, obviously not and I indicated that in my answer. Will expand.